# Make one row in result table from two rows in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Title changed! The problem is to merge rows to columns.**

I tag images (table Image) in a data base using a table (ImageAttribute) which has basically two rows - one for attribute type and the other for the value.

The database is:

```
Image.id
Image.URI
ImageAttribute.imageId
ImageAttribute.attributeType
ImageAttribute.attributeValue
```

ImageAttribute.imageId refers to Image.id

One image may have many attributes. e.g:

```
imageId | attributeType | attributeValue
--------+---------------+---------------
1       |COLOR          | blue
1       |QUALITY        | good
1       |MEMO           | some notes for image 1
2       |COLOR          | red
2       |QUALITY        | good
2       |OBJECTS        | cars, trees
```

From image to image the attributes set may differ.

Is it possible to select all images having attribute COLOR with any value and having QUALITY='good'  and display this information in one row e.g.:

```
id      | COLOR         | QUALITY        
--------+---------------+---------------
1       |blue           | good
2       |red            | good
```

Comment: Sigh, don't store data as attributeType / attributeValue pairs, it's a mess. Different columns or tables is the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use conditional aggregation to basically `pivot` your results:

```
select imageid, 
       max(case when attributetype = 'color' then attributevalue end) Color,
       max(case when attributetype = 'quality' then attributevalue end) Quality
from imageattribute
group by imageid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44e67/1)

---

If you need to filter only results with `quality = good`, then you can add a `having` statement:

```
having max(case when attributetype = 'quality' then attributevalue end) = 'good'
```

- [More Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59d9a/1)

Comment: It's fantastic! I have some troubles to understand the syntax, but this seems to be some advanced usage of SQL. Have to learn it :-)

Answer (score 2):

This statement also seems to work (and you can use the SQL fiddle link provided by sgedded which is very usefull to test queries).

```
SELECT im1.imageId as id, im1.attributeValue as COLOR, im2.attributeValue as QUALITY
FROM imageattribute im1, imageattribute im2
WHERE im1.imageId = im2.imageId
AND im1.attributeType = "COLOR"
AND im2.attributeType = "QUALITY"
AND im2.attributeValue = "good"
```

Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Awful, but works too :)

```
SELECT A1.imageId, A1.attributeValue, A2.attributeValue
FROM ImageAttribute as A1
INNER JOIN ImageAttribute AS A2 ON A2.imageId=A1.imageId
WHERE A1.attributeType='QUALITY' AND A1.attributeValue='good' AND A2.attributeType='COLOR'
```

Comment: Interesting usage of `AS`! (P.S.:Hi Manuel! Was für ein Zufall!)